# How to interpret Isaiah 9:6?

Tags: isaiah, bible-versions

Jews: For a child has been born to us, a son given to us, and the authority is upon his shoulder, and the wondrous adviser, the mighty God, the everlasting Father, called his name, "the prince of peace."
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34228/what-does-isaiah-96-mean/34229#34229

So basically, according to jews, the mighty everlasting father is not the child but a divine being that called the child "the prince of peace"

Christian: For to us a child is born, to us a son is given, and the government will be on his shoulders. And he will be called Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God, Everlasting Father, Prince of Peace.
http://biblehub.com/isaiah/9-6.htm

Okay this quite different. The difference is definitely ideological rather than in grammar. But if we check the grammar, what would we think?

Comment: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/should-the-title-in-isaiah-9-be-translated?rq=1 looks like even the jewish translation think that the string of words are part of the child's name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Hebrew of the Masoretic text states,

> כִּי יֶלֶד יֻלַּד לָנוּ בֵּן נִתַּן לָנוּ וַתְּהִי הַמִּשְׂרָה עַל שִׁכְמוֹ וַיִּקְרָא שְׁמוֹ פֶּלֶא יוֹעֵץ אֵל גִּבּוֹר אֲבִיעַד שַׂר שָׁלוֹם

1. כִּי (*ki*) : a conjunction, meaning “for”.
2. יֶלֶד (*yeled*): a noun that can refer to “a child” (cf. Gen. 21:8; Exo. 1:17–18, 2:3, etc.) or even “a young man” (cf. Gen. 4:23). However, the following verb יֻלַּד (“was born”) indicates that it is a “child”, a newborn.
3. יֻלַּד (*yullad*): a verb conjugated in binyan Puʿal, 3rd person, masculine gender, singular number, and perfect tense, meaning “was born”.<sup>1</sup>
4. לָנוּ (*lanu*): The preposition -ל with a 1st person, plural number pronominal suffix, meaning “to/ for us”.
5. בֵּן (*ben*): a noun meaning “a son”. Whereas a יֶלֶד is usually limited to a particular age range, a בֵּן is not.
6. נִתַּן (*nittan*): a verb conjugated in binyan Nifʿal, 3rd person, masculine gender, singular number, and perfect tense, meaning “was given”.<sup>1</sup>
7. לָנוּ (*lanu*): see #4.
8. וַתְּהִי (*vatehi*): a verb conjugated in binyan Paʿal, 3rd person, feminine gender, singular number, and imperfect tense, prefixed with *vav ha-hipukh* (conversive/ consecutive vav), meaning “and [subject] was”. (The following word is the subject of the verb.)<sup>1</sup>
9. הַמִּשְׂרָה (*ha-misrah*): a definite noun, rare, only occurring twice, in Isa. 9:6–7. The LXX translates it as ἀρχὴ, perhaps in the sense of “rule”. If this noun is derived from the root ש-ר-ר, then it is related to the verb שָׂרַר (*sarar*), meaning “to rule, govern”, and the noun שַׂר (*sar*), meaning “ruler”. Thus, הַמִּשְׂרָה would likely mean “rule” or “dominion”.
10. עַל (*al*): a preposition, meaning “upon”.
11. שִׁכְמוֹ (*shikhmo*): a noun with a 3rd person, masculine gender, singular number pronominal suffix, meaning “his shoulder”.
12. וַיִּקְרָא (*vayikra*): a verb conjugated in binyan Paʿal, 3rd person, masculine gender, singular number, and imperfect tense, prefixed with *vav ha-hipukh* (conversive/ consecutive vav), literally meaning “and [subject] called”. But, understood as “and [his name] was called”.<sup>1, 2</sup>
13. שְׁמוֹ (*shmo*): a noun with a 3rd person, masculine gender, singular number pronominal suffix, meaning “his name”.
14. פֶּלֶא (*pele*): a noun, meaning “wonder” or “miracle” (cf. Exo. 15:11).
15. יוֹעֵץ (*yo'etz*): an active participle, conjugated in binyan Paʿal, masculine gender, singular number, meaning “counselor”.
16. אֵל גִּבּוֹר (*el gibbor*): the noun אֵל meaning, “God”, followed by the adjective גִּבּוֹר, meaning “mighty”. Altogether, “mighty God” (cf. Isa. 10:21).
17. אֲבִיעַד (*aviad*): a phrase consisting of the noun אֲבִי in the construct state, meaning “father of”, and עַד, meaning “eternity”. Altogether, literally meaning “father of eternity”, but understood as “eternal father” (cf. Hab. 3:6: “eternal mountains”).
18. שַׂר שָׁלוֹם (*sar shalom*): a phrase consisting of the noun שַׂר, meaning “ruler, prince”, and שָׁלוֹם, meaning “peace”. Altogether, meaning “prince/ ruler of peace”.

Translation:

> For a child was born for us,
> a son was given to us,
> and the rule was upon his shoulder,
> and his name was called,
> “Wonder, Counselor, Mighty God, Eternal father, Prince of peace”.

---

| Footnotes |
| --- |
| <sup>1</sup> Because the verbs יֻלַּד ,נִתַּן, and וַתְּהִי are conjugaed in the perfect tense (and translated in English past tense), some object to the notion that this prophecy by Isaiah could apply to anyone who lived in the future (e.g., Jesus). However, note the words of the Jewish grammarian and commentator David Kimchi (RaDaK) on this subject. In his *Sefer Mikhlol*, Folio [12b](https://books.google.com/books?id=d6Q6yG0RkaEC&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false), he wrote, [image: David Kimchi, Sefer Mikhlol, Folio 12b, Venice: Bomberg, 1545] ותדע כי מנהג העוברי׳ בלשון הקדש להשתמש בו עבד במקום עתיד שהן אותיות א״יתן וזה בנבואות ברוב כי הדבר ברור כמו אם עבר כי כבר נגזר׳ And you should know that it is a typical behavior of the past tense verbs in the holy language to use a past tense verb in place of a future tense verb (which are [indicated by] the letters איתן), and this is mostly in prophecies because the matter is clear as if it passed, because it has already been decreed. <sup>2</sup> It should be noted that some verbs, although conjugated in binyan Paʿal, assume a meaning as though conjugated in a passive binyan (e.g., Nifʿal), when there is no explicit mention of a subject. For example, קָרָא in Gen. 16:14, which is understood as “the well **was called**...” rather than “he called the well...” See also Gen. 11:9, 19:22; Exo. 15:23; etc.; Gesenius, *Hebrew Grammar*, p. 460, [§144d](https://archive.org/details/geseniushebrewgr00geseuoft/geseniushebrewgr00geseuoft/page/460/mode/2up?view=theater). |

| References |
| --- |
| Gesenius, Heinrich Friedrich Wilhelm. [*Hebrew Grammar.*](https://archive.org/details/geseniushebrewgr00geseuoft) 2nd ed. Trans. Cowley, Arthur Ernest. Oxford: Clarendon, 1910. Kimchi, David (דוד קמחי). [*Sefer Mikhlol*](https://books.google.com/books?id=d6Q6yG0RkaEC) (ספר מכלול). Venice: Bomberg, 1545. |

Comment: So, the jewish translation was wrong? Or is there any way it can be right? I mean I asked that in a stackexchange filled with hebrew speaking jews here.

Comment: Oh that Vayikra seems to be the one ambiguous. It could mean and Called (by) mighty God, prince of peace. It could also mean and he is called mighty God, prince of peace.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34228/what-does-isaiah-96-mean/34229#comment88077_34229) isn't a fair characterization of your reasoning here, is it?

Comment: @Jim it's worth remembering that translation is as much art as science. All translation is done through an interpretive lens and the difficulties in correctly understanding any text are considerable (though not, I believe, insurmountably so).

Comment: @JimThio: There is nothing "telling" about my choice of "and his name was called" as opposed to "and he called his name." As it stands, there is NO subject for the verb וַיִּקְרָא. To say that "פֶּלֶא יוֹעֵץ אֵל גִּבּוֹר אֲבִיעַד" is the subject but then שַׂר שָׁלוֹם is the name of the object (i.e., his name), is quite arbitrary and "telling" in its own right. I noticed that another individual said that the child could not be called "mighty God"..."Because only God is called Mighty God, and not any of God's creations." Err...that's assuming the premise that the child is NOT God.

Comment: קָרָא שְׁמָהּ בָּבֶל - (Gen. 11:9) who called its name Bavel? Is the subject of the verb referring to a singular, masculine-gender subject, as the noun קָרָא suggests (based on its conjugation)? No, it's not. The Hebrew is understood as "its name was called (passive) Bavel." Isa. 9:6 is no different. The only difference is just that the verb is a imperfect w/ vav ha-hipukh, which effectively makes it perfect. But, in Gen. 11:9, the verb is written perfect. וַיִּקְרָא = קָרָא. No difference. Same phenomenon.

Comment: I see. So the jews presume that the child is not God and it's not plain reading.

Comment: But then what about the tenses. You said was born was given. This seems to refer to a child that has been born. Not to mention the perfect tenses.

Comment: If the child was born, it can't refer to Jesus either. In fact perfect tenses mean it should read the child has been born to us. Not the child is born or the child was born.

Comment: @JimThio: About the past tense of "was born" and "was given," you'd be wrong there. Let me edit my post and demonstrate why.

Comment: yullad (I prefer transliteration because my knowledge of hebrew words is limited) is perfect tenses right? So it should be "has been born"

Comment: @JimThio: Yes, it is "perfect tense." The translation "was born" is fine. Biblical Hebrew verbs only have a past (some call it "perfect") and a future (some call it "imperfect"). They don't exactly correlate to English, so to think the perfect must be translated as "has been born" (like the English perfect) isn't accurate. In general, "perfect" refers to completed events, whereas "imperfect" does not (Biblical Hebrew imperfect includes English present and future tenses). And I edited my original post to include some information for you.

Comment: I see. That still shows that it's a child that was born in the past. Not a future child. So it's still not Jesus.

Comment: @JimThio: I'm wondering if you actually read Radak's comment? "And you should know that it is a typical behavior of the past tense verbs in the holy language to use the past tense in place of the future tense (which is marked by the letters איתן), and this is mostly in prophecies because the matter is clear as if past, because it has already been decreed."

Comment: Ah ya... I've heard that. Prophetic perfect tense. Atheists would say that it's a case of post diction. Christians believe that it's written long before the event but use past tense as if God, being outside of time, have seen it. While I am skeptical, we can all agree there is no certainty in meaning here.

Comment: Christians **and** Jews believe that. David Kimchi was an Orthodox Jewish rabbi. The only thing I would agree with is that it speaks of Jesus. Anything but that, I consider nonsense. :)

Comment: Ah I see. Wow. But still, even though it supposedly refer to Jesus, it should still be translated as "was born" rather than "is born". I mean past tense should become past tense right? So how come all christians interpretation use the word is? Whether it's actually prophetic perfect or really just past tense should be up to readers, not translators. Not doing so means inserting interpretation or theology into translations and that's dishonest.

Comment: @JimThio: I did translate it as "was born," right? :)

Comment: You did. But most christian translations do not. http://biblehub.com/isaiah/9-6.htm

Comment: @JimThio: I agree with you.

Comment: What the septuagint says about this? How do jews translate it when they make septuagint. Should be a different question

Comment: Even the jews seem to agree with your translation. http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/should-the-title-in-isaiah-9-be-translated?rq=1  The Wonder, Counselor, Mighty God, Eternal father, Prince of peace is part of the child's name

Comment: Regarding your 'well' example. Gen 16:14  How about "[whoever(masculine) called the well] called the well"   One doesn't need to, and probably shouldn't, translate the Paal  like it's passive when translating, if being very accurate with the translation. Even in the extreme case of Gen 16:14 when the subject is unknown

Comment: The whole verse is written in past tense, it was spoken as if it had already happened, which is quite amazing. Christians believe Micah 5 is speaking of the Messiah being from "the days of eternity". Also "the Lamb of God slain from the foundation of the world. So past tense is acceptable, as God is not stuck in time and speaks of things as though that they already were. The also believe that the verse is speaking to them today and it also fits well in past tense. What you are missing though is that "Aviad" should be translated "My Father Is Eternal".